# Jenkins Kubernetes - SSL issues PKIXCertPathValidator when trying to run jobs on slave pods

Tags: java, kubernetes, jenkins, certificate, jcasc

For some reason, when I try to test my kubernetes plugin connection, I get this error when using my image.
It worked before, and now it doesn't.

I'm not sure what caused it, did anyone see this error before?

Logs -

```
java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Path does not chain with any of the trust anchors
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:157)
    at java.base/sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:83)
    at java.base/java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:309)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:364)
Caused: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path validation failed
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:369)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
    at java.base/sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:313)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:222)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T12CertificateConsumer.checkServerCerts(CertificateMessage.java:638)
```

[image]

UPDATE -
When I'm using the default jenkins/jenkins image I'm getting this error -

```
Error testing connection https://kubernetes.default: mapping values are not allowed here
in 'reader', line 1, column 6:
    sh: 1: aws: not found
         ^
```